# Radio buttons are not displayed (android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

My app displays a questionnaire for patients. The patients can choose the answers with radiobuttons. The radiobuttons are displayed in the browser chrome 
 with emulator ripple, but not in the app (android version 4.1.2)

HTML file:

```
<body>

<div class ="h1"> Patientenfragebogen </div>

<form name = "question">

    <div class="question">
        <p id ="Question1"> </p>
        <div id="displayPossibleAnswers"> </div>
    </div>


    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit" id="weiter" onclick="saveAnswer()">Weiter</button>
    </div>

</form>

</body>
```

JS file:

```
   for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        {
            //add radiobuttons (q= "radio" ; value = contains chosen answer)
            $('#displayPossibleAnswers').append("<input id='radio" + i + "' type=" + q +" name='answer' value=" + value[i] +">");
            //add label and possible answers
            $('#displayPossibleAnswers').append("<label id='value" + i + "'>" + value[i] + "</label>");
            $('#displayPossibleAnswers').append("&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        }
```

In the emulator it looks like this (This is how it should look like in the app):

[App Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YQQs.jpg)

Does anyone know where I am wrong? Is there another possibility to display the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You are going in wrong way. Change your Javascript and HTML code to:

```js
$(":radio").click(function () {
   $("span").text($(":radio:checked").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class ="h1"> Patientenfragebogen </div>

<form name = "question">

   <label for="inpt1_1">
      <input type="radio" id="inpt1_1" name="CheckBtn" value="testValue" /> with value
   </label><br>
    <label for="inpt1_2">
      <input type="radio" id="inpt1_2" name="CheckBtn" /> without value
    </label><br>
    the value is: <span></span>


    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit" id="weiter" onclick="saveAnswer()">Weiter</button>
    </div>

</form>

</body>
```

After selected radio button control that value with javascript / or use an ajax call. Its on you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to create and append the buttons in js because I get the input type and the values from a xml file which I access with DOM. See the follwoing xml - document
`

Comment: ` 
 <ItemDef OID="ID.Question1.radioBut" Name="Question1" DataType="string" Comment="radio">
            <Question>
               <TranslatedText xml:lang="de">Hatten Sie in der letzten Woche deutliche Atemnot?</TranslatedText>
            </Question>
            <CodeListRef CodeListOID="Q1" />
         </ItemDef>

Comment: <CodeList OID="Q1" Name="Question1" DataType="text">
            <CodeListItem CodedValue="Ja">
               <Decode>
                  <TranslatedText xml:lang="de">Ja</TranslatedText>
               </Decode>
            </CodeListItem>
            <CodeListItem CodedValue="Nein">
               <Decode>
                  <TranslatedText xml:lang="de">Nein</TranslatedText>
               </Decode>
            </CodeListItem>
         </CodeList>

Comment: @Nele then everything seems fine with your HTML and javascript.. I think there is some other work which android can't make

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem! :)

we changed the js code to:

```
for(var i = 0; i < answers[keyAnswer[counter]].length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < answers[keyAnswer[counter]][i].length; j++)
    {
        //display radiobuttons and labels
        document.getElementById("testForm").innerHTML += "<input id='radio" + j + "' type=" + q +" name='answer' value=" + answers[keyAnswer[counter]][i][j] +"/>  <label id='value" + j + "'>" + answers[keyAnswer[counter]][i][j] + "</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    }
}
```

it works without using jquery...

HTML file:

```
<body>

<div class ="h1"> Patientenfragebogen </div>

<div class="question">
<form id= "testForm" name = "question">
<p id ="Question1"> </p>
<div id="displayPossibleAnswers">

</div>
</div>


<div class="button">
<button type="submit" id="weiter" onclick="saveAnswer()">Weiter</button>
</div>


</form>

</body>
```